# Oracle SQL - How to preserve formatting - Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a text area items where users use regular formatting (e.g. adding a new line for new paragraph). Issue us, I need to export this data, so instead of a new line (when exported) I get nothing.
For example, on the frontend:
Test
Text

On the export:
TestText

How can I preserve formatting?

Thanks

Comment: What does "export this data" mean in this context?  The `exp` or `expdp` program?  Or something else?  Are you sure that the formatting characters are getting saved to the database correctly?

Comment: thank you @JustinCave, I perhaps used the incorrect term. But basically input is going into an email template. And yes, data is being stored correctly (e.g. 'this is some<br>text').

Comment: What exactly are you saving?  Are you saving HTML like the `<br>` tag implies?  Carriage return and line feed characters?  Something else?  Are you putting these into a plain text email?  Or an HTML email?

Comment: I'm saving user input, which is a text field Item. 
Since this is stored into the DB directly (meaning no format applied) I was thinking on using <br> (mostly) for new paragraphs. This item value then gets used in an HTML Email template I have already

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  You say you're "thinking on using" which implies that you are not currently storing HTML formatting tags.  If you are currently storing carriage return and line feed characters and inserting those unescaped into an HTML email template, you'll lose your formatting because HTML ignores whitespace in text by default.  But I have no idea if that's the problem you're actually having because I'm still unclear exactly what you are currently doing.

Comment: thank you @JustinCave. This is it: I have a form with a single Text Item, where the user will add text. This text will have paragraphs, meaning after each paragraph a new line will start. Once the user is done I'm storing this data into a table in the DB. Like you said, it evidently has no formatting. Then I would use this stored data to send it on an HTML Email template (data replaces Email placeholder). Which is why I was adding <br> whenever a paragraph ended (thinking this would reflect correctly on the email once sent). But it doesn't. Which is why I now ask how to preserve formatting

Comment: OK.  So you have an APEX form with a text item.  You enter text including HTML into this text item and save it.   If you query the data in the database, are you seeing the HTML stored correctly there?  You then have defined an APEX email template.  That template has appropriate substitution strings defined.  You are calling `apex_mail.send` with the appropriate `p_template_static_id` and `p_placeholders` is passing in the data you have confirmed has the correct HTML.  You get an HTML email out the other side but the HTML from your text item is missing.  Is that about it?

Comment: If so, please update your question to include that reproducible test case so we can see exactly what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is (most probably) that emails are sending html formatted text and you're using plain text as the source. In plain text the carriage return will be the newline ascii character. However, in html, a newline is represented by `<br>`. So, I'd suggest replacing the carriage return with `<br>` before generating the email text.

The ASCII code for carriage return is 13 and the one for line feed is 10. Use the [chr](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/CHR.html#GUID-35FEE007-D49C-4562-A904-041186AC8928) function to search for the those characters in your source string. So in your code, do a
`replace( l_text, chr(10), '<BR>' )` and/or `replace( l_text, chr(13), '<BR>' )`. Have a play with it to see what return character is used in your case.